# Merge multidimensional array values by shared key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Working with a single array in PHP, I'd like to merge like with like and am able to do so but I only get 1 return where there should be 2.

Below is the original array, and the new.

```
    id LIKE 'fghij' OR id LIKE 'abcde' 

   $orig = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field2] => height
                [value2] => 40 ft.
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field3] => width
                [value3] => 10-15 ft.
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field4] => light
                [value4] => Full - Partial
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field6] => space
                [value6] => 5-6 ft.
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field2] => height
                [value2] => 4-8 ft.
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field3] => width
                [value3] => 3-4 ft.
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field4] => light
                [value4] => Full - Partial
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field5] => season
                [value5] => Spring
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field6] => space
                [value6] => 4 ft.
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => fghij
                [field19] => restricted
                [value19] => CA, TX, LA, FL, AZ
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field19] => restricted
                [value19] => AZ
            )

    )
   $new = Array
    (
        [id] => abcde
        [field2] => height
        [value2] => 4-8 ft.
        [field3] => width
        [value3] => 3-4 ft.
        [field4] => light
        [value4] => Full - Partial
        [field6] => space
        [value6] => 4 ft.
        [field5] => season
        [value5] => Spring
        [field19] => restricted
        [value19] => AZ
    )
```

`$new` is so close to being correct but it ignores everything relating to `fghij`, returning a single flattened array. I'd like it to return both id's with their merged values.

This is where I'm at code wise:

```
$new_new = [];
foreach($orig as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    $new_new = array_merge($new_new, $value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accumulate the entries for each unique id.

```
function mergeByKey($array,$key){
    $result = [];
    foreach($array as $entry){
        $is_new = true;
        foreach($result as &$result_entry){
            if($result_entry[$key]==$entry[$key]){
                $is_new = false;
                $result_entry = array_merge($result_entry,$entry);
                break;
            }
        }
        if($is_new)
            $result[] = $entry;
    }
    return $result;
}

$new_new = mergeByKey($orig,'id');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is rad! I was going to write out each key with a catch if the key were missing but this is far easier on the eyes and fingers (and I'm not confident my way was going to work).

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this will work for you? You can add additional checks for $value['id'].

```
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    if( !array_key_exists($value['id'],$new) ){
        $new[$value['id']] = [];
    }  
    $new[$value['id']] = array_merge($new[$value['id']], $value );
  }
}
```

I'v change mine algorithm and now it's work as I expected.

Comment: This returns only the last value in the array:
```Array
            (
                [id] => abcde
                [field19] => restricted
                [value19] => AZ
            )
```

Comment: And yes... I'v changed it. Check it now, if you still interested.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works with the added benefit of setting 'id' as the index key, very cool!